# Force calculated member to evaluate at leaf level before aggregation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have found this solution:

```
    with calculated member [Measures].[Test1] 
as 
 iif (isleaf([Time].[Calendar].currentmember)), 
[Measures].[Measure1]/[Measures].[Measure2], 
Sum([Time].[Calendar].currentmember.children, [Measures].[Test1]))

    select Test1 on 0,
    [Time].[Calendar]. members on 1
    from 
    [MyCube]
```

and it works.

But I am wondering is it possible to have two dimensions or more, and to write something like this:

```
    with calculated member [Measures].[Test1] as 
    iif (isleaf([Time].[Calendar].currentmember)) and  isleaf([SecondDimension].[SecondDimensionHierarchy].currentmember), 
[Measures].[Measure1]/[Measures].[Measure2], 
**Sum([Time].[Calendar].currentmember.children, [Measures].[Test1])**)

   select Test1 on 0,
    [Time].[Calendar]. members on 1
    from 
    [MyCube]
```

I tried this and I am getting correct results for leaves, but empty values for higher members - I don't know how to write this sum`Sum([Time].[Calendar].currentmember.children, [Measures].[Test1])` when I have two hierarchies. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution:

```
with calculated member [Measures].[Test1] as 
    iif (isleaf([Time].[Calendar].currentmember)) and  isleaf([SecondDimension].[SecondDimensionHierarchy].currentmember), 
[Measures].[Measure1]/[Measures].[Measure2], 
Sum((DESCENDANTS([Time].[Calendar].currentmember, , LEAVES) * DESCENDANTS([SecondDimension].[SecondDimensionHierarchy].currentmember, , LEAVES), [Measures].[Test1]))

   select Test1 on 0,
    [Time].[Calendar]. members on 1
    from 
    [MyCube]
```